# ElasticSearch 5: MapperParserException with multi_field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping

This mapping hast worked with ES 2.X, now with ES 5 I get an exception:

```
{  
"type1":{  
    "properties":{  
        "name":{  
            "type":"multi_field",
            "fields":{  
                "name":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "index_analyzer":"standard",
                    "index":"analyzed",
                    "store":"no",
                    "search_analyzer":"standard"
                },
                "name_autocomplete":{  
                    "type":"string",
                    "index_analyzer":"autocomplete",
                    "index":"analyzed",
                    "store":"no",
                    "search_analyzer":"standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The exception is:

*No handler for type [multi_field] declared on field [name]*

Someone an idea? Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`multi-field` was deprecated in ES 1.x and completely removed in ES 5.x.

Now multi fields are supported via the use of [`fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/multi-fields.html) which you can specify like this:

```
{  
  "type1":{  
    "properties":{  
        "name":{  
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"standard",
            "index":"analyzed",
            "store":"no",
            "search_analyzer":"standard"
            "fields": {
                "autocomplete":{  
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer":"autocomplete",
                    "index":"analyzed",
                    "store":"no",
                    "search_analyzer":"standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you insert documents into this? Like this? PUT index/type1/1
{
    "name" : {
      "autocomplete": "Jose Sebastian"
    }
}

Comment: @sheldon_cooper you should probably ask another question as it doesn't look like it's related.

Comment: @Val  too have problem in inserting data when the mapping is like above. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508156/elasticsearch-5-mapperparserexception-while-inserting-data/45508332#45508332) to  the question I have opened. Looking at your above suggestion I have updated my mappings.