# Multifield in Elastic4s 5.x

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm currently using Elastic4s v5.0, which still has the multifield type used to index a field in more than one way.

```
elasticClient.execute(createIndex("foo") mappings (
  mapping("bar").as(
    multiField("baz").as(
      textField("baz") analyzer myAnalyzer,
      textField("original") index NotAnalyzed
    )
  )
)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
No handler for type [multi_field] declared on field []
```

The answer [ElasticSearch 5: MapperParserException with multi_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301061/elasticsearch-5-mapperparserexception-with-multi-field) and documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html says to use "fields" instead, but I cannot find how to do this in elastic4s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Elasticsearch any multifield has a *primary* field which is kind of like a parent field and then it has secondary fields. The primary field (primary and secondary is my terminology by the way), is accessed with `a` and the secondary fields are accessed as `a.b`, `a.c` and so on.

This might not be how you would first imagine a multi field to be, because you might just think that there's `a`, `b`, `c` as siblings like a kind of sequence. So its worth understanding this.

In elastic4s, you can just use `.fields` on any field you want, and then those fields will be combined with the *parent* to become a multi field. So your example re-written would be.

```
  client.execute {
    createIndex("foo").mappings(
      mapping("bar").fields(
        textField("baz").fields(
          textField("inner1") analyzer PatternAnalyzer,
          textField("inner2") index NotAnalyzed
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

Note that `as` is an alias for `fields` and I think `fields` is more readable so I used it here.