# ElasticSearch 5: MapperParserException while Inserting data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

My initial mapping was

```
{
  "vehiclemodel": {
    "properties": {
      "price": {
        "type": "double"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Later I updated the mapping with below

```
{
  "vehiclemodel": {
    "properties": {
      "price": {
        "type": "double",
        "fields": {
          "exShowroomPrice": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I add **Data1** it getting added, but when I add **Data2** it throws below exception

**Data1** :

```
{
  "price": 36992043     
}
```

**Data2** :

```
{
  "price": {
    "exShowroomPrice": 36992043
  }
}
```

**Exception** :

```
{
    'index': {
        '_index': 'notes',
        '_type': 'vehiclemodel',
        '_id': 'fb85823a-021b-468c-91d9-8db5f001ee06',
        'status': 400,
        'error': {
            'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception',
            'reason': 'failed to parse [price]',
            'caused_by': {
                'type': 'json_parse_exception',
                'reason': 'Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@6e2393ee; line: 1, column: 277]'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My collection`vehiclemodel` has both type of data in **MongoDB**. I am using mongo-connector to sync data btw mongo and ES. When I try to sync I get the above exception

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping is not correct for what I assume you want to achieve.

The [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) mapping allows you to index **the same** field with different analyzers for example (see the linked docs for details). So in your case, you would push

```
{
    "price" : 1923
}
```

and ES will store it twice, once as `price` and once under the path `price.exShowroomPrice`.

You could just add a completely separate property, the hierarchy does not need to be maintained. For example a mapping like:

```
{
    "vehiclemodel": {
        "properties": {
            "price": {
                "type": "double"
            },
            "exShowroomPrice": {
                "type": "double"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then send the data like:

```
{
    "price" : 1923
    "exShowroomPrice" : 1800
}
```

I don't know how mongo-connector works, but there should be a way to map these fields I would assume.

Comment: Here `exShowroomPrice` is a separate field. In my case I want `exShowroomPrice` as nested under `price` and also I want both **Data1** and **Datat2** need to be inserted. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301061/elasticsearch-5-mapperparserexception-with-multi-field) which I refered to update my mapping

Comment: Probably impossible, because in Data1 `price` is a double, and in Data2 it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Fields in elasticsearch mappings are thought to index the same field in different ways, such as processing the input field as a string or as a keyword. So you defined price as a double but elasticsearch finds an {} so this exception is thrown. You have to remodel your data there.

Comment: For me remodeling the data is bit difficult. So Is there a option to update the mapping so that I can insert both type of data?

Comment: Yes, you can keep the "price": double and add a simple exShowroomPrice: double.